# 0x1a STOP error occuring randomly

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit

I've been getting this stop error for like the seventh time already, i was hoping if anyone can help me read the bugcheck result:

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

MEMORY_MANAGEMENT (1a)
    # Any other values for parameter 1 must be individually examined.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000041284, A PTE or the working set list is corrupt.
Arg2: 0000000010ab6001
Arg3: 000000000000f130
Arg4: fffff70001080000

Debugging Details:
------------------


BUGCHECK_STR:  0x1a_41284

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN7_DRIVER_FAULT

PROCESS_NAME:  chrome.exe

CURRENT_IRQL:  0

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 6.3.9431.0 (debuggers(dbg).130615-1214) amd64fre

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff80004b34717 to fffff80004addb80

STACK_TEXT:  
fffff880`093b35c8 fffff800`04b34717 : 00000000`0000001a 00000000`00041284 00000000`10ab6001 00000000`0000f130 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
fffff880`093b35d0 fffff800`04b0ef10 : fffff700`01080000 93000001`cf2b4867 ffffffff`ffffffff fffff800`04c11d0e : nt! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'+0x4ad3
fffff880`093b3610 fffff800`04aca3cf : fffffa80`00000000 00000000`10b7dfff 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!MiDeleteVirtualAddresses+0x4e8
fffff880`093b37d0 fffff800`04adce13 : ffffffff`ffffffff fffff880`093b3aa0 fffff880`093b3b08 00000000`00008000 : nt!NtFreeVirtualMemory+0x61f
fffff880`093b38d0 fffff800`04ad93d0 : fffff960`00137458 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000000 fffff900`c2bc6cc0 : nt!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd+0x13
fffff880`093b3a68 fffff960`00137458 : 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000000 fffff900`c2bc6cc0 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiServiceLinkage
fffff880`093b3a70 fffff960`001377a8 : ffffffff`00000000 fffff880`00000000 fffff900`c2bc6cc0 00000000`00000000 : win32k!SURFACE::bDeleteSurface+0x3c8
fffff880`093b3bc0 fffff960`000f81ed : ffffffff`a5051694 fffff900`c2bc6cc0 00000000`00001694 00000000`00000002 : win32k!bDeleteSurface+0x34
fffff880`093b3bf0 fffff800`04adce13 : fffffa80`06e8e060 00000000`0000018c fffff880`093b3bf8 fffffa80`0a97f060 : win32k!NtGdiDeleteObjectApp+0xd5
fffff880`093b3c20 00000000`74b22e09 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd+0x13
00000000`001be4f8 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : 0x74b22e09


STACK_COMMAND:  kb

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
win32k!SURFACE::bDeleteSurface+3c8
fffff960`00137458 e9b0010000      jmp     win32k!SURFACE::bDeleteSurface+0x57d (fffff960`0013760d)

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  6

SYMBOL_NAME:  win32k!SURFACE::bDeleteSurface+3c8

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: win32k

IMAGE_NAME:  win32k.sys

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  5202f253

IMAGE_VERSION:  6.1.7601.18233

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x1a_41284_win32k!SURFACE::bDeleteSurface+3c8

BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x1a_41284_win32k!SURFACE::bDeleteSurface+3c8

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  KM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:x64_0x1a_41284_win32k!surface::bdeletesurface+3c8

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {296c97c3-bb12-bf14-0aea-632f56546f93}

Followup: MachineOwner
---------

0: kd> lmvm win32k
start             end                 module name
fffff960`00070000 fffff960`00387000   win32k     (pdb symbols)          c:\symbols\win32k.pdb\99227A2085CE41969CD5A06F7CC20F522\win32k.pdb
    Loaded symbol image file: win32k.sys
    Mapped memory image file: c:\symbols\win32k.sys\5202F253317000\win32k.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\System32\win32k.sys
    Image name: win32k.sys
    Timestamp:        Thu Aug 08 02:20:19 2013 (5202F253)
    CheckSum:         0031170D
    ImageSize:        00317000
    File version:     6.1.7601.18233
    Product version:  6.1.7601.18233
    File flags:       0 (Mask 3F)
    File OS:          40004 NT Win32
    File type:        3.7 Driver
    File date:        00000000.00000000
    Translations:     0409.04b0
    CompanyName:      Microsoft Corporation
    ProductName:      Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
    InternalName:     win32k.sys
    OriginalFilename: win32k.sys
    ProductVersion:   6.1.7601.18233
    FileVersion:      6.1.7601.18233 (win7sp1_gdr.130807-1534)
    FileDescription:  Multi-User Win32 Driver
    LegalCopyright:   © Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

My system is running a windows 7 x64, 2x4GB ram.

Comment: The first step would be to make sure this happens with a brand new Chrome profile.

Comment: sure, but i don't know how to make it happen, the stop error, since it happens randomly.

Comment: This means you will have to determine what action causes it.

Comment: Enable Driver Verifier ?

Answer (score 1):

This code `win32k!SURFACE::bDeleteSurface` sounds like  GPU issue, so update the graphic card drivers or disable HW acceleration inside chrome.